# Broadcast Upload Extension（NSExtensionPointIdentifier：com.apple.broadcast-services-upload）toRecord the screen

Tags: ios

I created a new project and added Broadcast Upload Extension. In iOS 11 control center Record the screen function I can choose My Extension and select start live, when system work to Record screen, I can't get any Callback. How should I do, that can work for me?